# Problem with interpolating function returned by NDEigensystem

Tags: interpolation, finite-element-method

I'm trying to evaluate interpolating function returned by NDEigensystem at a point but Mathematica won't evaluate it.

```
{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 4];
 f = funs[[3]] (*3rd eigenfunction*)
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, Pi}] (*this plot returns blank plot*)
Plot[f, {x, 0, Pi}] (*this plot works fine*)
f[2]
```

As you can see, f[2] is not evaluated. Any help with the problem with the plot and function evaluation would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `u[x]` to `u`

```
{vals, funs} =NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u , {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 4]
```

now

```
Plot[funs[[3]][x],{x,0,Pi}]
```

does what you are looking for.

To plot all the eigenfunctions try `Plot[Through[funs[x]],{x,0,Pi}]`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my problem.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: On a related note, how can I define new functions using my interpolating function f (or manipulate interpolating functions in general)? For example in my above code, if I define ff=f+2 or ff=2*f, I'm not able to evaluate this function (e.g., ff[2] does not evaluate). Or how can I define new function ff= Sin[x]*f for example?

Comment: Try `ff = FunctionInterpolation[2  funs[[3]][x], {x, 0, Pi}]` or `fff = Function[{x}, funs[[3]][x] + 2]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I noticed however that this method introduces large errors. For example, defining `ff = FunctionInterpolation[funs[[3]][x], {x, 0, Pi}]` (same as original function f) and comparing ff and f(by plotting ff[x]-f[x]), I found ff[x] to significantly deviate from f[x]. Hence I'm afraid that using FunctionInterpolation will introduce large errors.

Comment: There are no errors in both variants( of my comment). Perhaps the second variant is preferable.